# c# - Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

I'm having a problem D:

I have a JSON string as follows and want to deserialize it:

```
[
      {
        "id": 37547411,
        "user_id": 116082,
        "identifier": "quest_stage1",
        "status": 1,
        "ts_complete": 0,
        "used_resources": 0,
        "rewards": "{\"coins\":14,\"xp\":213,\"honor\":0,\"premium\":0,\"statPoints\":0,\"item\":19628919}"
      },
      {
        "id": 37547416,
        "user_id": 116082,
        "identifier": "quest_stage2",
        "status": 1,
        "ts_complete": 0,
        "used_resources": 0,
        "rewards": "{\"coins\":6,\"xp\":600,\"honor\":0,\"premium\":0,\"statPoints\":0,\"item\":0}"
      }
    ]
```

my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

 string json = responseString;

 JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

JToken teste = obj["data"]["quests"];

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(teste.ToString());

dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

my classe:

```
 public class JsonResult
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public int status { get; set; }

        public rewards rewards { get; set; }
    }


        public class rewards
        {
            public int coins { get; set; }
            public int xp { get; set; }
        }
```

I need get the value coins and xp and puts it in datagridview

example:
 [image: example image]

But I am getting the error below:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Error converting value "{"coins":14,"xp":213,"honor":0,"premium":0,"statPoints":0,"item":19628919}"]
```

I do not know what to do, I've tried various methods found on the Internet and none worked, I'm not very good with it = /

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is in your JSON string, you are representing the Rewards sub object as a string. Remove the quotes around it and unescape the other quotes inside it.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
problem solved.